# Oracle copy data to another table

Tags: sql, oracle

In the Oracle, I copy data from a backup to a new table, it doesn't work.

what is the correct syntax ?

Thanks

```
select CODE, MESSAGE into EXCEPTION_CODES (CODE, MESSAGE)
from Exception_code_tmp
```

the error is

```
**SQL Error: ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"**
```

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You need an `INSERT ... SELECT`

```
INSERT INTO exception_codes( code, message )
  SELECT code, message
    FROM exception_code_tmp
```

Comment: superb..!! its simple and easy to use. but what if there are more columns lets say - 25-30 columns

Comment: @BN - You'd just list all the columns.  If you know that both tables have exactly the same set of columns in exactly the same order you could do a `SELECT *`.  That's generally not what I'd recommend for production code but it's reasonable for a one-off ad hoc.

Answer (score 61):

If you want to create table with data . First create the table :

```
create table new_table as ( select * from old_table);
```

and then insert

```
insert into new_table ( select * from old_table);
```

If you want to create table without data . You can use :

```
create table new_table as ( select * from old_table where 1=0);
```

Comment: The 'insert into' is redundant since the 'create table as' will create table and insert all data.

Comment: but aside from being redundant in this context, i just wandered here looking to insert data from one table to another, which this does. So the Answer actually gives more options than just answer for this question.

Comment: I came for the same reason. I have used create table as select initially to populate the records. However the source table has new records which need to be added on top of existing records in target table. This helps in that case.

Comment: @Clomez the answer does gives more options, but the way it is written is wrong due the proposed sequence of 'create as' followed by 'insert' which is redundant, as mentioned by @ thoredge. The answer needs editing.

Comment: @thoredge unfortunately 'create table as' doesn't copy indexes from the original table. any idea how to get them copied too? 'insert into' is way too slow (hours)...

Answer (score 11):

Creating a table and copying the data in a single command:

```
create table T_NEW as
  select * from T;
```

* This will **not** copy PKs, FKs, Triggers, etc.

Comment: Copies constraints on table, like not null. Thanks :)

Comment: Is there a way to copy PKs & FKs ?

Comment: @NathanGoings - sounds like a question to put on SO :)

Answer (score 6):

```
insert into EXCEPTION_CODES (CODE, MESSAGE)
select CODE, MESSAGE from Exception_code_tmp
```

Comment: doesn't seem so according to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250196/select-into-using-oracle)

Answer (score 0):

```
create table xyz_new as select * from xyz where 1=0;
```

http://www.codeassists.com/questions/oracle/copy-table-data-to-new-table-in-oracle