# Load data simultaneously in 10 table

Tags: oracle

My Requirement : I have 72 oracle tables which have data inside it. Few tables have billion and million of records. I need to copy data from 72 tables to another 72 tables as it is. What is best way to do it ? I want to copy the data at one shot in 5-6 tables so that it should not go and load data one by one in-order to save the time. Not sure how should i achieve it in oracle.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle copy data to another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11472519/oracle-copy-data-to-another-table)

Comment: Are the tables in the same database?  (If so, then there's a regular SQL solution, otherwise something like datapump might be fastest.)  What edition of the database do you have?  (If Enterprise Edition, then parallel options will likely help with the performance.)

Comment: All the tables in same database.using enterprise edition. Here the catch is we need to truncate the table daily and load all 72 tables. We need some kind of script which can run insert select statement parallel for set of tables. For example - out of 72 tables, in 5 tables data should insert simultaneously. Once it's complete next 5 tables should start.

Comment: Do you need to rotate data between tables?
Then it may be easier for you to rename the tables into archived tables and create new tables for insertion? It will be very fast and effective!

Answer (score 2):

If both the source and target tables are present in the Database schema then you can follow below approach:

a.) Create a configuration table with the metadata information to define the rules and create the custom insert statement for the tables. (Optional)

b.) Write a procedure with the logic to move the data from one table to another.

c.) Write a procedure with DBMS_SCHEDULER in a loop to schedule the call the copy procedure defined in step b). The scheduler will take case of opening and closing a session.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can use some ETL tool. To get migrate all data in diferents ways or tables.

Some like Pentaho ETL tool. Here you can create your diagram and run that. And all will be ok. Pentaho have a commuty server tool too. 
[Pentaho Data Integration or ETL](https://www.etltool.com/etl-vendors/pentaho-data-integration-kettle/)

The ETL tool will give you the chance to extract your data, transform in whatever you want and load in any table or database.

**Update**

This is the ETL tool. As I can remmember is aviable for windows and linux and maybe MAC.

[ETL community tool](https://github.com/cwarden/kettle)

Answer (score 0):

[The fastest way to do this will probably be to use the SQL*Plus COPY command](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/apb.htm#SQPUG140). Oracle swears up and down they're going to deprecate COPY but given that it's widely used by their customers I think they'll keep it around for quite a while. Note that if you want to copy multiple tables simultaneously you'll have to use multiple connections to the database, because as far as I'm aware there's no way to issue a COPY command which doesn't wait for the copy operation to finish before letting you issue another COPY command.

Best of luck.

Comment: All the tables in same database.using enterprise edition. Here the catch is we need to truncate the table daily and load all 72 tables. We need some kind of script which can run insert select statement parallel for set of tables. For example - out of 72 tables, in 5 tables data should insert simultaneously. Once it's complete next 5 tables should start. Something like running in batch.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to copy tables within the same database is to use Oracle parallelism, not concurrency.  Run the SQL one-at-a-time, in parallel, instead of running multiple statements at the same time.

The words parallelism and concurrency mean slightly different things in Oracle.  Parallelism is a feature available with Enterprise Edition; the database will create parallel sessions to divide and monitor the work.  Concurrency is when you manually create and monitor separate processes that do things at the same time.

Parallelism is usually much easier than concurrency.  It often only requires a single hint to enable it (although there are many complex ramifications of those simple hints).  Concurrency requires you to create and monitor scheduler jobs.

Parallelism is usually much faster than concurrency.  Oracle can probably do a better job of evenly distributing work than you can.  Parallelism breaks the work into granules and allocates them to parallel processes as needed.  It's not perfect but it's usually pretty good.  Compare that with concurrency, where you are responsible for finding X tables that process equally as fast.  Finding X equally sized tables is more difficult than you might think, and getting it wrong is ruinous for performance.

Here's a procedure that will load a set of tables with parallelism.  You'll probably want to verify that each statement is getting direct-path write and parallelism - you may need to disable foreign keys, enable NOLOGGING, disable triggers, etc.  It can take hours to get this right.

```
create or replace procedure parallel_load
--Purpose: Copy data from source tables to destination tables.
--This procedure truncates target tables - there is no turning back!
(
    p_source_schema in varchar2,
    p_target_schema in varchar2,
    p_tables sys.odcivarchar2list,
    p_dop number
) authid current_user is
    v_sql varchar2(32767);
begin
    --Enable parallel DML for parallel writing.
    execute immediate 'alter session enable parallel dml';

    --Loop through the tables.
    for i in 1 .. p_tables.count loop
        begin
            --Truncate the target table.
            execute immediate 'truncate table '||p_target_schema||'.'||p_tables(i);

            --Create parallel insert.
            v_sql := 
                replace(replace(replace(replace(
                    q'[
                        insert /*+ parallel(#DOP#) */ into #TARGET_SCHEMA#.#TABLE_NAME#
                        select * from #SOURCE_SCHEMA#.#TABLE_NAME#
                    ]'
                , '#DOP#', p_dop)
                , '#TARGET_SCHEMA#', p_target_schema)
                , '#TABLE_NAME#', p_tables(i))
                , '#SOURCE_SCHEMA#', p_source_schema);

            --Execute the parallel insert.
            execute immediate v_sql;

            --Must commit if direct-path writes are used.
            commit;
        exception when others then
            raise_application_error(-20000, 'Error with this SQL: '||v_sql||chr(10)||
                sys.dbms_utility.format_error_stack||sys.dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace);
        end;
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Here's an example of calling it.  (Finding the right DOP is tricky, try experimenting with different numbers, and look at the `cpu_count` and `%parallel%` parameters in `V$PARAMETER`.)

```
begin
    parallel_load(
        p_source_schema => 'source_schema',
        p_target_schema => 'target_schema',
        p_tables        => sys.odcivarchar2list('test1', 'test2', 'test3'),
        p_dop           => 8
    );
end;
/
```

You almost certainly do *NOT* want to use DBMS_SCHEDULER, an ETL program, or the COPY command.  Those solutions will be much more complicated and slower than parallelism.  (No offense to those who posted those answers.  They were posted
 before the critical comment explaining that the tables are inside the same database.)