# Alter Physical Structure of table Oracle11gr2

Tags: sql, database, oracle, database-design

I have a table

```
Name              Age                    RollNo.
A                  1                      10
B                  2                      20
```

Now I want to alter the table permanently in such a way that,After altering it should look as below

```
RollNo.           Name                    Age
10                 A                      1
20                 B                      2
```

How shall i alter this table , All i want to do is to change physical structure of the table.

Comment: I think not. why do you want to alter it? you can always rearrange them through `SELECT` statements

Comment: Yes but in Database i want to alter this table. With select i know i can alter it. @JW

Comment: Akki please see my answer

Comment: Yes it is the simplest way i have seen but can you please help me with altering physical structure of the table @tammy

Comment: well, is it possible to create a new table? If yes then create a new table with the correct positioning and create a script which could fetch the existing data from the old table into the new table.

Comment: Unfortunately Oracle only allows columns to be added to the end of an existing table or creating a view is pretty much what I could think of.

Comment: @tammy         its difficult creating new table because the table has many other dependencies such as triggers,procedures

Comment: The order of columns in a table is irrelevant. There is no need to do it.

Answer (score 3):

**Why** do you want to do it?

If it's just because you'd like to have a correct order of columns when using `SELECT *`, then you should not have used `*` in the first place. Always use the exact list of columns in your queries.

If it's because you think it would improve the performance, have you done the actual measurements? I doubt you'll find many scenarios where changing the physical column order influences performance in a significant way. There are some scenarios with chained rows where it might (see the "Row Chaining" section in [this article](http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_chained_rows.html)), but that doesn't apply to narrow rows such as yours.

---

That being said, you could:

- `CREATE TABLE NEW_TABLE AS SELECT <different column order> FROM OLD_TABLE`.
- Recreate all the relevant constraints (such as keys, FKs), indexes and triggers/procedures on the `NEW_TABLE`.
- `DROP TABLE OLD_TABLE`.
- `ALTER TABLE NEW_TABLE RENAME TO OLD_TABLE`.

You might also want to look at the [dbms_redefinition](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_dbms_redefinition.htm) if you need to do that while accepting updates.

Comment: I am not viewing it by typing query such as Select. I am using Oracle11gr2 where I can directly view the table graphically in SQL Developer  @Branko Dimitrijevic

Comment: @Akki Then just rearrange the columns in the SQL Developer UI: either drag-and-drop column headers, or use the _Columns..._ option from the context-menu (right-click on column headers). BTW, this is not related to any particular Oracle database version - this is purely a client-side operation.

Comment: Yes by dragging and dropping column header i am able to view it in the order i need thanks @Branko Dimitrijevic

Answer (score 0):

You can drop and create the table without loosing the data in oracle using statement

```
create table YOUR_TABLE_BU as select * from YOUR_TABLE
```

Please go through the link - [How can I create a copy of an Oracle table without copying the data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233870/how-can-i-create-a-copy-of-an-oracle-table-without-copying-the-data) for more details. Try:

```
CREATE TABLE YOUR_TABLE_BU AS SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE;

DROP TABLE YOUR_TABLE;

CREATE TABLE YOUR_TABLE AS SELECT RollNo., Name, Age FROM YOUR_TABLE_BU;

DROP TABLE YOUR_TABLE_BU;
```